# Angular unit test failed . (Nullinjector error)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, user-interface, frontend

This is the edited question, before that i didn't add reactiveformsmodule in spec file,

Now I have add reactiveformsmodule in spec.ts file,

I don't know weather the issue has been resolved or not(No provider for formbuilder). still facing the same 95 errors , Is anything wrong with my app.spec.ts file

[image]

But still i am facing same 95 errors in application, I don't know weather the error has been gone or not

**ts file**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CapacityReservationListComponent } from './capacity-reservation-list.component';

describe('CapacityReservationListComponent', () => {
  let component: CapacityReservationListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CapacityReservationListComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CapacityReservationListComponent ],
      imports:[FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CapacityReservationListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
describe('AppComponent', () => {

    it('Should launsh the application ', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is explicit : `FormBuilder` has no provider.

Since `FormBuidler` is part of the `ReactiveFormsModule`, you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` when configuring the TestBed.

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
     ReactiveFormsModule 
   ],
 })
```

Comment: I have added this ReactiveFormsModule in specs file, but error count are still same(95), I don't know weather this error is gone or not. .can you pls give any suggestion to find out this? and why it is still same error count.